# What's the right way to `subscribe`/`assign` to a Kafka topic using .NET `Confluent.Kafka`?

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, task-parallel-library, confluent-platform

```
Task.Run(
                        () =>
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                var (topic, partitionOrNull, offsetOrNull) = target;

                                if (partitionOrNull == null && offsetOrNull == null) consumer.Subscribe(topic);
                                else
                                {
                                    var partition = partitionOrNull ?? 0;
                                    if (offsetOrNull != null) consumer.Assign(new TopicPartitionOffset(topic, partition, offsetOrNull.Value));
                                    else consumer.Assign(new TopicPartition(topic, partition));
                                } 

                                while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                                {
                                    var consumeResult = consumer.Consume(cancellationToken);

                                    if (consumeResult.IsPartitionEOF) continue;

                                    observer.OnNext((consumeResult.Offset.Value, consumeResult.Key, consumeResult.Value));
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception exception)
                            {
                                observer.OnError(exception);
                            }
                        },
                        cancellationToken);

                    return Task.FromResult<IDisposable>(consumer);
                });
```

So there is a Kafka consumer (just a tiny wrapper around latest `Confluent.Kafka`) that covers both scenarios: `subscribe` with dynaimc rebalancing and `assign`ing to a specified partition and/or offset. The problem is that when I specify only `topic` (`partition == null && offset == null`), consumer infinitely hangs without any progress. Am I misusing the framework or what's going on?

P.S. Specifying all three parameters accurately works prefectly fine.

Comment: what is `target`? why would partitions or offsets be null?

Comment: @cricket_007, target is a triple (3-tuple) of `topic, partition, offset`. `null` stands for "I don't want to specify this parameter explicitly; use default".

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoints or logging in your while loop?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this one?